# Javascript Array Consistent Traversing

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check if a Javascript array has 5 consistent member of same value. so

```
function checkArray(value,array){
    for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      if (array[i]==value){

    }       
  }
} 

var a=[2,3,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,7],
    b=[4,4,4,5,5,4,5,5,5,4]

checkArray(5,a) //return true
checkArray(5,b) //return false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var a = [2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7],
    b = [4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4];

function checkArray(num, len, array) {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length - len; i += 1) {
        var flag = true;
        for (var j = i; j < i + len && flag; j += 1) {
            flag = array[j] === num;
        }
        if (flag) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.assert(checkArray(5, 5, a) === true);
console.assert(checkArray(5, 5, b) === false);
console.assert(checkArray(4, 3, b) === true);
```

Here `num` is the number to be found, `len` is the length of the consecutive items to be matched.